# Run a bash command when a process is done

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have two scripts that use GPU and train ML models. I want to start them before I go to sleep so they work at the night and I expect to see some results in the morning.

But because of the GPU memory is limited, I want to run them in serial instead of parallel.

I can do it with `python train_v1.py && python train_v2.py`; but let's say I started to train the `train_v1`. In the mean time, because the training takes long time, I started and finished the implementation of the second script, `train_v2.py`, and I want to run it automatically when `python train_v1.py` is finished.

How can I achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: With `python train_v1.py && python train_v2py`, you'll run `python train_v1.py` and only after that completes *successfully* will it run `python train_v2.py`.  That sounds like what you're after.

Comment: If you don't care about the exit status of the first program, use `python v1; python v2`

Comment: To clarify: are you saying that, when you start `python train_v1.py`, you don't yet know whether you'll have a second program to run (or, similarly, what exactly the second command will be)? And that you can't/are not willing to simply start `python foo && python bar && python baz` and then just ensure that the programs you are still writing will be named `bar` and `baz`? (Noting that the shell won't complain if, when you run `foo && bar`, `bar` doesn't exist yet; it will only complain if `bar` does not exist when `foo`terminates).

Comment: Possibly useful: [Simple queuing system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/19458/315749)

Comment: The OP already knows about `&&`.  This question is clearly about achieving the same effect *after* the first program has already been started.

Comment: I suspect snakemake could help you achieve something close to what you want.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's an approach that doesn't involve looping and checking if the other process is still alive, or calling `train_v1.py` in a manner different from what you'd normally do:

```
$ python train_v1.py
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 python train_v1.py
$ % && python train_v2.py
```

The `^Z` is me pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> while the process is running to sleep `train_v1.py` through sending it a `SIGTSTP` signal. Then, I tell the shell to wake it with `%`, using it as a command to which I can add the `&& python train_v2.py` at the end. This makes it behave just as if you'd done `python train_v1.py && python train_v2.py` from the very beginning.

Instead of `%`, you can also use `fg`. It's the same thing. If you want to learn more about these types of features of the shell, you can read about them in [the "JOB CONTROL" section of bash's manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control).

#### EDIT: How to keep adding to the queue

As pointed out by jamesdlin in a comment, if you try to continue the pattern to add `train_v3.py` for example before v2 starts, you'll find that you can't:

```
$ % && python train_v2.py
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 python train_v1.py
```

Only `train_v1.py` gets stopped because `train_v2.py` hasn't started, and you can't stop/suspend/sleep something that hasn't even started.

```
$ % && python train_v3.py
```

would result in the same as

```
python train_v1.py && python train_v3.py
```

because `%` corresponds to the last suspended process. Instead of trying to add `v3` like that, one should instead use history:

```
$ !! && python train_v3.py
% && python train_v2.py && python train_v3.py
```

One can do history expansion like above, or recall the last command with a keybinding (like up) and add v3 to the end.

```
$ % && python train_v2.py && python train_v3.py
```

That's something that can be repeated to add more to the pipeline.

```
$ !! && python train_v3.py
% && python train_v2.py && python train_v3.py
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 python train_v1.py
$ !! && python train_v4.py
% && python train_v2.py && python train_v3.py && python train_v4.py
```

Comment: This is the only reliable solution and the simplest one to boot.

Comment: In this particular case, the programs don't depend on each other apart from using the same resources (you want to run the second program even if the first one exits with an error), so it's better to use the semicolon (`fg; python train_v2.py`) instead of the short-circuiting `&&`.

Comment: @Bass Well, that depends on what the OP wants. I just did as they did in their question. Perhaps, if v1 fails they want to see the error message at the bottom of the terminal, even if the 2 are independent. Using `;` would obscure that.

Comment: +1 I can't believe I've wanted this ability for a while, and it never occurred to me that `fg && ...` would work.  However, it might be worth noting that it doesn't seem that you can continue to chain.  For example, you can't do the suspend + `fg && process` multiple times to get the equivalent of `process && process && process`. (Similarly, I only now realize that if I do `process1 && process2` and suspend before `process2` starts, `process2` will not be invoked if I resume with a plain `fg`.)

Comment: @jamesdlin Right, because `fg`/`%` wakes the last suspended process, and since `process2` wasn't invoked yet, you can't suspend it. In that scenario, I would use the history to facilitate adding to the pipeline. I've added to the answer to address that.

Answer (score 11):

If you have already started `python train_v1.py`, you could possibly use `pgrep` to poll that process until it disappears, and then run your second Python script:

```
while pgrep -u "$USER" -fx 'python train_v1.py' >/dev/null
do
    # sleep for a minute
    sleep 60
done
python train_v2.py
```

By using `-f` and `-x` you match against the exact command line that was used to launch the first Python script.  On some systems, `pgrep` implements a `-q` option, which makes it quiet (just like `grep -q`), which means that the redirection to `/dev/null` wouldn't be needed.

The `-u` option restricts the match to commands that you are running (and not a friend or other person on the same system).

If you haven't started the first script yet:

As mentioned in comments, you could just launch the second script straight after the first script. The fact that the second script does not exist, or isn't quite ready to run yet, does not matter (as long as it ready to run when the first script finishes):

```
python train_v1.py; python train_v2.py
```

Doing it this way will launch the second script regardless of the exit status of the first script.  Using `&&` instead of `;`, as you show in the question, will also work, but will require the first script to finish successfully for the second script to start.

Comment: First one is really useful, thank you! And yes, I can use the second one too in most cases, but first one is neat.

Comment: I'd prefer running `ps` once to find out the pid of that first script, then run a loop like `while kill -0 <pid>`. Had it happen way too often that `pgrep` (or `killall`) found something that wasn't intended, especially on multi-user systems. Btw, `kill -0` won't do anything to the killed process, it just checks if that process is still there.

Comment: @GuntramBlohmsupportsMonica You could obviously use `pgrep -u "$USER" ...` on a multi-user system. Using `pgrep` would also avoid issues arising from PID reuse on heavily used systems.

Comment: This method is brittle, as shown by the above comments, and complex too.

Answer (score 6):

You can launch the first script with

```
python train_v1.py; touch finished
```

Then simply make a loop that checks regularly if `finished` exists:

```
while [ ! -f finished ] ; do     
    sleep 5
done
python train_v2.py
rm finished
```

Comment: I haven't tried yet but that seems like exactly what I'm looking for. I will try it asap.

Comment: Where's the advantage over `python train_v1.py; python train_v2.py` ?

Comment: @GuntramBlohmsupportsMonica I'd say it is more customizable and, above all, you don't need to bother to choose the second program beforehand. Those considerations apart, there is no advantage.

Answer (score 2):

You can always simply [`wait`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-wait) for a running program by passing the program ID as a parameter. The PID can be obtained from a `ps` call. To make it robust in a script is difficult, which is why programs which anticipate that somebody wants to wait for  (or kill) them usually write their own PID into a known location. But for the interactive situation you describe looking the PID up and copying it is easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to know the exit status of the first script, then I recommend something like [what Kusalananda wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572632/621).

If you do need to know the exit status (which you probably don't in this case, but someone else may come along looking for a solution that does this), it's more complicated. I've written a [small Linux utility `pwait`](https://github.com/diazona/pwait) that lets you wait for a process to finish and find out its exit status.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in Linux (with a `bash` avaliable) it would be as easy as:

**TL;DR: use this:**

```
((python train_v1.py; kill $(cat ./pid) && rm ./pid) &

python train_v2.py & echo $! > pid
```

**The longer version:**

You create a sub-shell where your training V1 is running - when V1 finished (regardless of the return code - if you want to check for a return code of 0, use `&&` instead of `;`) the output of a file named `pid` is provided to the kill application and if kill returns successful the `pid` file is removed.

Afterwards you start the second training and write the process ID of the second training to a file named `pid` and there the cycle is closed. now both training programs run in the background until python `train_v1.py` is finished.

Comment: _"now both training programs run in the background..."_ But OP wants to run V2 _after_ V1 (and `pkill -F pid` can read the PID from a file).